# Prove that $\neg \forall x P(x) \leftrightarrow \exists x \neg P(x)$

Tags: logic, quantifiers

I am reading "How To Prove It" by Velleman, the 2nd Edition.

At page 65 Velleman presents the "Quantifier negation rules"

$$\neg \exists x P(x) \text{ is equivalent to } \forall x \neg P(x) \tag{1}$$
$$ \neg \forall x P(x) \text{ is equivalent to } \exists x \neg P(x) \tag{2}$$

justifying them with some exemples.

Then he talks about various demonstration methods and at page 128, talking about demonstration strategies involving biconditionals, he proves by contraddiction the $(1)$:

- he first proves $\forall x \neg P(x) \to \neg \exists x P(x)$: he assumes $\forall x \neg P(x)$ and $\exists x P(x)$ (i.e. the negation of $\neg \exists x P(x)$), then from $\exists x P(x)$ he derives $P(x_{0})$, that contraddicts $\forall x \neg P(x)$ beacause from this he derives $\neg P(x_{0})$;
- after he proves $\neg \exists x P(x) \to \forall x \neg P(x)$: he assumes $\neg \exists x P(x)$ and takes an arbitrary $x$ and supposes $P(x)$, from that he derives $\exists x P(x)$ that contraddicts $\neg \exists x P(x)$, from that he concludes $\neg P(x)$ and since $x$ is arbitrary he arrives at $\forall x \neg P(x)$

Velleman says that in a similar way it can be proved also $(2)$. But I am not able to do it. How can I prove $(2)$ in a similar way?

EDIT.
There is a screen of pages 129-130 where Velleman proves $(1)$. I would like to $(2)$ in a similar way.
https://images2.imgbox.com/05/82/VqLyVoH0_o.png

Comment: I try to prove $\neg \forall x P(x) \to \exists x \neg P(x)$: I assume $\neg \forall x P(x)$ and $\neg \exists \neg P(x)$ and then... I don't know ho to continue. It seems to me all so strange...

Comment: @user1988 How do you have "there exists" defined? So then what does assuming those two together mean? It's a very quick contradiction when you get it. I'm working on the second one now

Comment: I can't understand your first hint. If I want to prove $\neg \forall x P(x) \to \exists x \neg P(x)$, my hypothesis is $\neg \forall x P(x)$ and $\exists x \neg P(x)$ is what I want to prove, so I can not assume it... Or I can?

Comment: @Vivic38 At page 55 Velleman says "To say that P(x) is true for every value of x in the universe of discourse
U, we will write ∀x P(x). We write ∃x P(x) to say that there is at least one value of x in the universe
for which P(x) is true."

Comment: @user1988 What a peculiar definition. Usually $\exists x \phi$ is defined as  $¬ \forall x ¬\phi$. Is this a derivation from axiom or is this just a semantic proof of the validity of these statements? If it is axiom it would help if you posted them, otherwise I can help you with a semantic proof.

Comment: There are not axioms. This book is not about formal logic, it is about proof strategies. Velleman uses the proof by contradiction to prove $(1)$ as I reported above. Look here: https://images2.imgbox.com/05/82/VqLyVoH0_o.png This is how he proves $(1)$. Now I would like to prove $(2)$ in a similar way.

Comment: @Vicvic38:  _How To Prove It_ does not give a formal axiomatic deduction system, but it gives informal rules for writing proofs (in English) that correspond to the rules of a formal natural deduction system.  So what is being asked for is a proof using those rules, which would be an informal version of formal natural deduction proof.  The rules are:  Given $\forall x P(x)$ you can infer $P(a)$.  To prove $\forall x P(x)$, let $x$ be arbitrary and prove $P(x)$.  Given $\exists x P(x)$ you can introduce a name $a$ for which $P(a)$ is true.  To prove $\exists x P(x)$, prove $P(a)$ for some $a$.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me to be a proof of the semantic validity of these statements (the word derivation threw me off slightly, made me think we wanted an axiomatic proof.) I will rewrite one those he's given in a way that I think is more illuminating and should help you work out the rest.

So for $¬ \exists x P(x) \to \forall x¬P(x)$

Assume we have that there is some way of putting variables (a variable assignment) into (a) $¬ \exists x P(x)$ and (b) $¬ \forall x¬P(x)$ that makes both of them true.

(a) gives us that there is no x such that $P(x)$ is true.

(b) gives us that there exists some x such that $¬P(x)$ is false (as it is not true for all x,) which means that for that x, $P(x)$ is true, giving a contradiction with a.

Therefore whenever (a) is true, (b) must be false and so we have the given implication.

I personally would have done this more directly but if he's looking at contradictions of this sort this is what you want to do.

As a general tip for proving validity, you want to assume there is some way of putting variables into the sentence that makes it false, then work through what the constituent parts to show that it leads to a contradiction in the logic of the sentence. Ted Sider has a good method in his Logic for Philosophy.

$¬ \forall xP(x) \to \exists x¬P(x)$

> We take (a) $¬ \forall xP(x)$ and (b) $¬\exists x¬P(x)$ as true under some variable assignment. (a) implies that there is some x such that $¬P(x)$ (as it's not true for all x.) Then (b) implies that there is no x such that $¬P(x)$ (as there does not exist an x for which it is true,) yielding the contradiction you seek.

$\exists x¬P(x) \to ¬ \forall xP(x)$

> We assume there is some variable assignment that makes $\exists x¬P(x)$ true. Then this gives us that there is some $x_0$ for which $¬P(x_0)$ is true.

> (I don't like his x is arbitrary so we have $¬ \forall xP(x)$ but if you wanted to conclude that way here, then you could.) The way I would conclude this is assume $\forall xP(x)$, but you've just shown that there exists an $x_0$ for which $¬P(x_0)$ is true and so $P(x_0)$ is false, so contradiction.

Comment: I'm OK with the proof of $(1)$. I understood it. I'm in trouble with $(2)$. I want to prove $\neg \forall x P(x) \leftrightarrow \exists x \neg P(x)$; the first thing I do is to split $\leftrightarrow$ so I have to prove $\neg \forall x P(x) \to \exists x \neg P(x) \tag{2a}$ and $\exists x \neg P(x) \to \neg \forall x P(x) \tag{2b}$. I start with $\text{(2a)}$: so I assume $\neg \forall x P(x)$ and $\neg \exists x \neg P(x)$ in order to obtain a contraddiction; now I do not know how to procede!

Comment: @User1988, The proof is very similar. Assume there is some x that makes both of them true, then show that leads to contradiction as I have done. I'm writing up the solutions (I'm not great with LaTeX, so it takes me a little bit) but really do try working through my method with your new assumptions first.

Comment: I'm OK with the second conditional. The first one instead seems strange to me. I explain beacause. You say "(a) implies that there is some $x$ such that $\neg P(x)$ (as it's not true for all $x$.)". Well: it seems to me like you are using exactly the property we want to prove, it seems to me like you are using the english language version of the property we want to prove. Am I wrong? It seems to me like you are using the property of the english language version of quantifiers.

Comment: @user1988 Well, alright, perhaps I didn't break it down far enough. So, it's not true that for all x, P(x). By the definition of the universal quantifier that you gave me, that means that there has to be at least one $x_0$ such that P(x) is not true (or rather ¬P(x)) otherwise it would be true for all x. The property of the english language version is what you've given me to work with.

Comment: OK, so let me to understand. If I define the quantifiers using the english language I'm defining the semantic of quantifiers using the english language. This implies that if I want to prove a property of quantifers using their meanings, I have to use the property of the language I used to declare the semantic of quantifiers. In this way the quantifiers translate in the formal language the property I'm talking about in english. Is it correct? Thanks.

Comment: @user1988 Yes, that's precisely it. When you move into Predicate calculus (if you take that route,) you use a very specific definiton of for all and exists, but if you've only got the english language definitions then thats the one you want to use (and is the one we tend to use in maths generally.)

Comment: @Vivic38 And what are the very specific definitions of "for all" and "exists" without using the english language?

Comment: @user1988 Well, it's not technically without using the english language, but if you formalise what a model/L-structure is, you then define for all with regards to variable assignment functions to your domain and your valuation function. You then define there exists to be not for all not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of how you can give a proof of (2) that is similar to the proof you quoted of (1):

For the $\to$ direction:  Assume $\neg\forall x P(x)$ and $\neg \exists x \neg P(x)$.  To get a contradiction, prove $\forall x P(x)$, which will contradict your assumption $\neg\forall x P(x)$.  You can do this by taking an arbitrary $x$ and proving $P(x)$.  To prove $P(x)$, use proof by contradiction.

For the $\leftarrow$ direction:  This direction is easier.  Assume $\exists x \neg P(x)$ and $\forall x P(x)$.  Since $\exists x \neg P(x)$, you can let $x_0$ be something such that $\neg P(x_0)$.  You can take it from there.

However, there is another possibility that might be easier:  You can use (1) to prove (2).  Hint:  Start by rewriting $\neg\forall x P(x)$ as $\neg \forall x \neg\neg P(x)$.

Comment: OK: let me to understand. Let's start with the first conditional. To prove $\neg \forall x P(x) \to \exists x \neg P(x)$ I have to use two times the proof by contraddiction technique, I have to use a proof by contraddiction into another proof by contraddiction. So let's go.
1. I assume  $\neg \forall x P(x)$;
2. I assume  $\neg \exists x \neg P(x)$;
3. The contraddiction I want to get is $\forall x P(x)$;

Comment: 4. To get the contraddiction in point $3$,  I prove by contraddiction that $\neg \exists x \neg P(x) \to \forall x P(x)$ so: (a) let's assume $\neg \exists x \neg P(x)$ and let's take an arbitrary $x_0$ such that $\neg P(x_0)$ is true; (b) if $\neg P(x_0)$ is true, than I can introduce $\exists$ and say $\exists x \neg P(x)$; (c) $\exists x \neg P(x)$ contraddicts the assumption $\neg \exists x \neg P(x)$, so I have to reject $\neg P(x_0)$ and take $\neg \neg P(x_0) \equiv P(x_0)$; (d) since $x_0$ is arbitrary, from $P(x_0)$ I can introduce $\forall$ and say $\forall x P(x)$;

Comment: 5. now I have that $\forall x P(x)$ contraddicts the assumption in point $1$, i.e. $\neg \forall x P(x)$, so I have to reject $\neg \exists x \neg P(x)$  and take $\neg \neg \exists x \neg P(x) \equiv \exists x \neg P(x)$

Comment: Is all OK? Is there something wrong?
Thanks

P.S.
Are you the same Velleman of the book?

Comment: Yes, that's all correct.  (You repeated yourself a bit by stating the assumption of $\neg\exists x\neg P(x)$ twice--once in your step 2 and then again in step 3, but that's a minor point.)  I suppose another way to phrase would be that you prove the contrapositive of the left-to-right direction of (2), which is $\neg \exists x \neg P(x) \to \forall x P(x)$.  And yes, I'm the author of the book.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I add the proof of the second conditinal: $\exists x \neg P(x) \to \neg \forall x P(x)$. Again by contraddiction: 1. I assume $\exists x \neg P(x)$; 2. I assume $ \neg \neg \forall x P(x) \equiv \forall x P(x) $; 3. Because of $\exists x \neg P(x)$, I can take $x_0$ such that $\neg P(x_0)$; 4. Because of $\forall x P(x)$, I also have $P(x_0)$; 5. Because of $5$ and $4$ I have a contraddiction, so I have to reject $\forall x P(x)$ and take $\neg \forall x P(x)$. P.S. IMHO Your book is one of the most clear books about proof strategies. Thanks for it.

Comment: Your proof of the right-to-left direction looks fine.  Glad you're enjoying the book.

Comment: Thank you for you patience and your hints.